# How to turn off the prettier trailing comma in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, trailing

How to turn off the prettier trailing comma in VS Code?

I go to settings. Select `none` for the prettier trailing comma. Restart VS Code. Select a piece of TypeScript, press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F` and the trailing commas still appear. How could I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a `.prettierrc` config file in your project that overrides the VSCode settings ?

Comment: @Ewaren, by searching in a project (`Ctrl` + `P` and typing the `.prettierrc`) I can not find such a file. But by searching through all the files (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F`) I can find a file `settings.json` and in the file I has only this: `{"prettier.trailingComma": "none"}`.

Comment: the `settings.json` file contains your workspace settings : it is just the JSON transcription of the settings you chose in VSCode's graphical interface. There must be a config file in your project overriding these settings, it would be easier to help you if you could show us the folder structure of your project (for example with the `tree -a` command).

Comment: @Ewaren, I am not sure where I should execute the command. My folder structure is an ordinary Angular app structure. I got it after running the `ng new angular-tour-of-heroes`. When I try to run the command in my project folder I am getting the error: `$ tree -a
bash: tree: command not found`

Comment: I just looked up the source code for Tour of Heroes, there is no .prettierrc file there, maybe the .editorconfig file introduces conflicts... Try adding a .prettierrc file at the root of your project, with `{ "trailingComma": "none" }` in it maybe.

Comment: @Ewaren, just have checked. That helped. Thank you a lot. Could you post your last comment as an answer, please? :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since you are working on the Tour of Heroes project, it is maybe the .editorconfig file there that introduces conflicts with your VSCode Prettier settings. Try adding the following .prettierrc file at the root of your project :

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

The .prettierrc file has the highest priority over any setting, so it should override any conflict.

Answer (score 14):

Adding this line to settings.json worked for me.

`"prettier.trailingComma": "none"`

Answer (score 13):

At the **root of the project** create the Prettier configuration file: `.prettierrc.json`

Add this code to your file: `.prettierrc.json`

```
{
    "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

**Save file** and then **restart your Visual Studio Code**

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same problem and I added this line in the settings and it worked for me.

```
"prettier.trailingComma": "none"
```

Comment: do you have a prettier extension installed? vscode tells me that this setting is uknown.

Comment: Yes I believe I do.

Answer (score 4):

In VS Code Settings, go to json file and type this:

```
"prettier.useEditorConfig": false
```

[image: Or just in the Setting, under Prettier configs, set this to false/uncheck to prevent prettier other config to take precedence over Prettier]

Comment: This is the solution to all the prettier related problems. I think we shouldn't be touching `.editorconfig` unless we are doing for the whole team

Answer (score 4):

[Prettier has the following rules](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) for where to look for settings (in order of precedence):

> - A "prettier" key in your package.json file.
> - A .prettierrc file written in JSON or YAML.
> - A .prettierrc.json, .prettierrc.yml, .prettierrc.yaml, or .prettierrc.json5 file.
> - A .prettierrc.js, .prettierrc.cjs, prettier.config.js, or prettier.config.cjs file that exports an object using module.exports.
> - A .prettierrc.toml file.

Following the first rule, I was able to configure it by adding the following to `package.json`

```
"prettier": {
  "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same experience as your screen recording. Restarting VSCode did the trick for me. I could not find a way to restart the prettier addon... maybe someone can chime in on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

```
npm run lint --fix
```

after formatting...

Comment: this doesn't change anything in the vscode settings.

Comment: @banushan-puviraj what do u refer by running `npm run lint --fix` you should have shared the `lint` script as well, not sure but u may have configured `lint` to 'eslint .` from scripts in packgage.json file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the configuration above was not enough.

For this to work for me, in addition to this setting, I had to remove from ***setting.json***:

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Next, enter the command
`ctrl + shift + P` in *vscode*

Click on `Configure...`

Choose `Prettier - Code formatter`

Now this:

```
const a = {
  a: 10,
  b: 15,
};
```

turns into this:

```
const a = {
  a: 10,
  b: 15
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in vs-code `settings.json`

```json
// remove semicolons
"prettier.semi": false
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty way, but works when the prettier doesn't help you much for some scenarios. Use this way if you have no other option**

Sometimes there will be a mixture of presence and absence of trailing commas in the code (as each developer might have written it and formatted differently which was my case), so none of the above solutions work.

If you are **doing a simple change** (like adding 2 or 3 lines of code and you don't want to change the format of other code), then do the following.

- First write your code as you normally do, save it. Prettier will modify your code and other code if "Format on Save" is turned on.
- Copy your formatted code. Revert the changed file (In vscode, you can click the revert (semi circle arrow) button to revert this file changes
- Turn off "Format on Save" feature in settings
- Paste your copied code to where you want and click on save
- Turn on the "Format on Save" again for future changes